# Use the $_POST method with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have a user driven website. Users can post whatever they want, even a picture. Now, I use PHP to store the posts in my database table and PHP and MySQL to retrieve display the posts on each user's profile. Now, I want to give the user the ability to delete a post they upload, and I want to use $_POST to do it, not $_GET. I already know how to do it with $_GET. How could I use $_POST? Could I just have a hidden form field next to each user post and have a hidden field holding the post_id and when the user hits the "delete post" submit button it calls the delete post.php script? Is that a good way to do it, through a hidden form field?

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much the way to do it via a hidden form field.  Be sure to check ownership of the object being deleted in your delete script to be sure any user can't delete any other user's.

Comment: Are you trying to build a REST interface? If yes, you should use DELETE, if not, why don't pass a URL parameter and use `$_GET`? Besides using a hidden form field you can also do a POST request using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just set your `form`'s `method` equal to `post`, then, have some kind of `input` of type `hidden`, with a `value` of the id to delete.

Then, in PHP, access that with `$_POST` rather than `$_GET`.

DO make sure to validate the deletion ID, so user's don't just edit the HTML with FireBug, and so on.

Comment: Validation is important: there is no guarantee that the data being posted even comes from your HTML form at all.